# kubernetes pods not showing running instead showing CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: twitter, kubernetes

While performing `Twitter` data migration from `Twitter` to `pubsub` and then to bigquery, I created 2 pods namely **bigquery controller** and **twitter-pubsub**. But when I give describe pods twitter-pubsub the status shows `CrashLoopbackOff`. What can be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the eventlog of your pod `kubectl describe pod twitter-stream-6p8ca` to see what the crash reason was. Look at your application's previous run logs to see if you can make sense of it `kubectl logs twitter-stream-6p8ca --previous`

Comment: Thanks Mark , I tried "kubectl describe pod twitter-stream-6p8ca",but could not decipher anything from that.It just dispays the message: Back-off restarting failed docker container.Any help !

Comment: Are you able to run your docker container locally? The error suggests that kubernetes is not able to start your container so your application contained in it is not running (so no application logs are available)

Comment: `kubectl describe` should show you the last termination status of container, which should include the exit code as well. The command show also show events happened within an hour. It'd help if you can post the output.